# absolute path to directory accessed by right click 'Show Package Contents'

Tags: macos, finder

In OS X Mountain Lion when you right click on an *.app icon you get an option to 'Show Package Contents' leading you into 'Contents' directory.

I'm having trouble figuring out the absolute path to the 'Contents' directory for a given *.app

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any .app is just a folder so if an application is in

```
 /Applications/Safari.app
```

the Contents directory is

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents
```

You can also get the path by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-clicking on the folder name at the top of the Finder window.

Comment: Thanks! that was easy. I assumed the .app files were not directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `terminal` app, and then drag any file or folder into it to have the full path displayed in text that you can copy/paste etc.